# Rmarkdown theme not applied in vignette using R CMD build

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, knitr, r-package

I'm trying to make a html package vignette with a specific theme, from example the *hpstr* theme from *prettydoc* (`https://github.com/yixuan/prettydoc/blob/master/vignettes/hpstr.Rmd).

If I build the vignette manually:

`rmarkdown::render('vignettes/hpstr.Rmd', output_format='prettydoc::html_pretty')`

the theme is applied correctly. However, when I use a standard build process, e.g.:

```
git clone https://github.com/yixuan/prettydoc.git
cd prettydoc
R CMD build .
R CMD INSTALL prettydoc_0.2.1.tar.gz
```

and then, in R:

```
> library('prettydoc')
> vignette('hpstr')
```

the theme is not rendered at all, it looks like a regular `html_output`.

The yml at the top of the vignette looks as follows:

```
---
title: "Creating Pretty Documents from R Markdown"
subtitle: "The HPSTR Theme"
author: "Yixuan Qiu"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: hpstr
    highlight: github
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Creating Pretty Documents from R Markdown - The HPSTR Theme}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

and in the `DESCRIPTION` file the vignette builder is specified:

```
VignetteBuilder: knitr, rmarkdown
```

So it looks like the vignette builder is some other than `rmarkdown::render`.

How can I apply the theme automatically with `R CMD build` ?

Comment: Not sure if it works in your case, but you can try to use its `css` [file](https://github.com/yixuan/prettydoc/blob/master/inst/resources/css/cayman.css) (for example) and put it on your directory

Comment: Put it in the top-level directory of the package? This doesn't work for me... And I have all the files in `inst/resources/css/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if pandoc is either not installed at system level or to old, while RStudio ships with its own version of pandoc. Therefore rendering in RStudio succeeds whereas it fails with `R CMD build`. Possible solutions:

- Install or update pandoc at system level
- Make the pandoc shipped with RStudio available at system level
- Build the package in RStudio (suggested by @YihuiXie)

Comment: This answer seems to be correct to me. If you build a package with Rmd vignettes outside of RStudio, you will have to make sure Pandoc is available at the system level (you could symlink RStudio's pandoc if you want). Since no `sessionInfo()` was provided, I cannot offer further help, but I think the easiest thing to do is just build the package in RStudio.

Comment: This worked, thanks! So if I understand correctly, if someone e.g. uses `devtools::install_github('yixuan/prettydoc', build_vignettes=T)` without or with an old pandoc, themes won't render?

Comment: So to distributed a nicely rendered vignette, a static one would be the best solution?

Comment: @user1981275 It will work if the installation happens within RStudio, since that includes a recent (enough) pandora version. That should cover a high proportion of users. Besides distributing a static vignette you could also try to use a configure file that tests the installed pandoc version.